# Hibernate: org.hibernate.criterion.ProjectionList cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

How to assign selected column values from Hibernate Criteria to bean class? When I try to assign the values to bean, it giving me the following error:

> ProjectionList cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Criteria.

Please see my code below which is getting that error:

```java
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PartFeatureVersion.class,"pfv");
criteria.createAlias("pfv.part", "p");
criteria.createAlias("pfv.featureVersion", "fv");
criteria.createAlias("pfv.dateRange", "d");
criteria.createAlias("fv.feature", "f");
criteria.setProjection((Projection) ((Criteria) Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("f.name"))
        .add(Projections.property("fv.versionName"))
        .add(Projections.property("d.startDate"))
        .add(Projections.property("d.endDate"))
        .add(Projections.property("fv.featureVersionId")))
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FeatureSearchResult.class)));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("pfv.part.id","p.partId"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("pfv.featureVersion.id","fv.featureVersionId"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("pfv.dateRange.id","d.dateRangeId"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("fv.feature.id","f.featureId"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("p.partNbr", partNo));


List list = criteria.list();
                Iterator it = list.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext())
                {
                FeatureSearchResult feature = (FeatureSearchResult)it.next();
                System.out.println(feature.getName());
                System.out.println(feature.getVersionName());

                }
```

Comment: remove casts, not necessary

Comment: if remove casts , its getting error as "The method setProjection(Projection) in the type Criteria is not applicable for the arguments (Criteria)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite `criteria.setProjection()` code as:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.property("f.name").as("name"))
  .add(Projections.property("fv.versionName").as("versionName"))
  .add(Projections.property("d.startDate").as("startDate"))
  .add(Projections.property("d.endDate").as("endDate"))
  .add(Projections.property("fv.featureVersionId").as("featureVersionId")));
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FeatureSearchResult.class));
```

and `FeatureSearchResult` is declared as (just an example, surely will differs from real definition):

```
class FeatureSearchResult {
  String name;
  String versionName;
  Date startDate;
  Date endDate;
  String featureVersionId;

  // Add getter/setter
}
```

`as()` method invocation is used put source property into the right `FeatureSearchResult`'s property.

I hope I was clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: I'm able to compile the code but those values not able to get through FeatureSearchResult.class , please advise.

Comment: I have pojo class , but not getting the values.

Comment: Does the query produce a non-empty result?

Comment: Yes, return the values butvalues are not getting into pojo class.

Comment: Did you change your original code with my modification (adding `.as(propertyName)`)?